# In MeterPlot, how to hide the value which appears at bottom

Tags: java, jfreechart

I want to know is there any way or method to hide or disable the value in `MeterPlot` using `JFreeChart` in Java. Here's the screenshot from this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19833774/230513), with the value circled in yellow.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: I've edited the question to cite the corresponding example.

Answer (score 2):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25416067/230513), one approach is to specify a zero-sized font with an empty `units` string:

```
meterplot.setValueFont(new Font(Font.SERIF, Font.PLAIN, 0));
meterplot.setUnits("");
```

[image]

Alternatively, subclass [`MeterPlot`](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/plot/MeterPlot.java) and then either

- Override `drawValueLabel()` to omit rendering:

  ```
    MeterPlot meterplot = new MeterPlot(valuedataset){
        @Override
        protected void drawValueLabel(Graphics2D g2, Rectangle2D area) {
        }
    };
  ```
- Add an attribute such as `valueVisible` and draw conditionally; add mutators, invoking `fireChangeEvent()` as warranted:

  ```
    private class MyMeterPlot extends MeterPlot {

        private boolean valueVisible;

        public MyMeterPlot(ValueDataset dataset) {
            super(dataset);
        }

        @Override
        protected void drawValueLabel(Graphics2D g2, Rectangle2D area) {
            if (valueVisible) {
                super.drawValueLabel(g2, area);
            }
        }

        public void setValueVisible(boolean valueVisible) {
            this.valueVisible = valueVisible;
            fireChangeEvent();
        }

        public boolean isValueVisible() {
            return valueVisible;
        }
    }
  ```

For reference, changes to support value visibility have been added to version 2.0 [here](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/commit/efae5e517dd80f31bd031cc5b62807be4dc662cc) and back ported to the upcoming version 1.5.4 [here](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/commit/06060900b5e6d2ec2687d910d2e5a453f3cbade1).